# How do I create content links to a group node without using panels?

Tags: organic-groups

I am new to Organic Groups and I am following the videos at https://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups-7x-2x . Video 4 demonstrates how to insert a create content link on a group page using Panels and I am able to replicate this, when following the video.

However, I would prefer not to use Panels and can not display a create content link in a basic layout (without Panels or Display Suite).

Various posts say that having entityreference_prepopulate module is key, but as far as I can tell, I have this configured properly (otherwise my panel wouldn't work).

I am expecting to see a display formatter on the content type or perhaps a module generated block, but nothing seems apparent.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Seems I needs to use install OG Extras -  https://www.drupal.org/project/og_extras